# How to send emoji via api in Onesignal

Tags: emoji, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal in my project and I want to send my message with an certain emoji via api (In my case, typescript).

In my message string I have for example, this:

> Hey, wake up! :flushed:

But on the Android device, I get the text with: flushed: in text format instead of the corresponding emoji.

Where am I going wrong or what am I letting go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***First method***

Copy an emoji from the web and paste that along with your message in API.

If the above method does not work,

***Second Method***

First of all, create a method

```
public String getMessageWithEmoji(String originalMessage){


    String convertedEmoji;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<emoji>(.*?)<emoji>").matcher(originalMessage);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        Log.e("extracted emoji",matcher.group(1));
        int hex = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1).substring(2), 16);
        convertedEmoji= String.valueOf(Character.toChars(hex));


        originalMessage=originalMessage.replace(matcher.group(),convertedEmoji);

    }

    return originalMessage;
}
```

inside your **NotificationExtenderExample** class (I am assuming that you have extended NotificationExtenderService class in your app. If not check this [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding)).

After doing this, add

```
 builder.setContentTitle(getMessageWithEmoji(receivedResult.payload.title));
```

inside your ***onNotificationProcessing*** method(For emoji in notification body, use ***setContentText***).

Send notification with emoji replaced with Unicode. Also, add `<emoji>` before and after your Unicode(this is to identify emoji inside the application).

For example, if you want to send

> hello user

use this

```
 <emoji>U+1F601<emoji> hello user <emoji>U+1F602<emoji>
```

For more emoji Unicode visit [here](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)